# How to fetch last transaction using Lex Bot after confirmation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-lex

I made a Lex Bot to order milk but whenever i completed the process and exit the bot my transaction got erased. I am not able to see my last transaction. I want to know how can i save my previous details so i can enquire it in future?

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) =>{
var amount = event.currentIntent.slots.amount;
var params1 = {
  Key: {
      "last_Transaction": {
     S: " "
    }, 


  }, 
  TableName: "confirmation_Table"
 };
dynamodb.getItem(params1, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
   else    
   {console.log(data);           // successful response

   }


 }); 


 callback(null, {
        "dialogAction":{
            "type":"Close",
            "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",

            "message": {
                "contentType": "PlainText",

                "content": amount


            }

        }
    });





};
```

Answer (score 1):

You should save the transactions in some file or database, where you can read them in future. [DynamoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) is good choice.

Before exiting the bot you can store the transaction with unique id in the DynamoDB.

You can use `put_item()`,read about them at [DynamoDB docs](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html)

Below is the pseudo code:

```
Get info from user  
Validate in DialogCodeHook  
Come to FulfillmentCodeHook  
Save info in DynamoDB
Close
```

Comment: Thanks i got u even i am thinking same but can you show me how can i achieve this? Means can you show me screen-shots so that i can do it asap. I am done with all other stuff just having this issue.

Comment: @Pulkit, i have added references and details, try it let us know if you run in problems. mark the answer as accepted if it helped and upvote. hope it helps.

Comment: i am able to save my transaction but not able to retrieve it back. i am uploading my code please review it.

Comment: i am getting empty data when i call my database table and access its key

Comment: sorry I don't know how to perform this in node.js, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#getItem-property this link might help you